# Run several 'make' command at the same time?

Tags: makefile, cmake

(*make* noob here)

I did the following:

1. Configured a C++ project with CMake.
2. In one terminal tab, ran *make* to start building the whole project.
3. Got bored of waiting for the whole thing to build, figured I could
   just *make* the subfolder I'm working on at the moment.
4. **Without stopping the ongoing build** in the first tab, opened a second tab and ran *make* from said subfolder.

Things looked pretty normal for a short while, then suddenly second tab started displaying build outputs related to the whole project, not only to the subfolder. I figured what I tried didn't work as I expected, so I CTRL-C'd the second tab.

That's when the weirdest happened: in the first tab the build output was mixed with lines coming form the specific folder I wanted to build. And the build went way past 100%, up to 128%!

My question is: **what exactly does 'make' do when launched more than once at the same time?**

Am I correct to think that the multiple make commands where somehow "merged" in the same process??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question about the makefiles that CMake creates and how they work.  It's these makefiles which do things like track the percent complete, etc., not `make` itself.  It's quite possible that by starting a second build in the same directory, you've messed up whatever facilities the CMake makefiles use to track progress.

The short answer is that no, it's not possible that one invocation of make will somehow "take over" or merge another invocation of make.  As far as the make program is concerned they know nothing about each other.  However since both are operating on the same filesystem, if one make writes files in a way that can confuse another make, you could see strange behaviors.

The cmake-generated makefiles are *very* complex; I've never actually tried to understand completely how they work.  I've always thought it a shame that no one has tried to implement a CMake `GNU Makefile` generator in addition to the `Unix Makefiles` generator, that took full advantage of GNU make features.  I'm sure the results would be easier to read and probably faster.  But it seems unlikely this will ever happen; CMake users who care more about speed than portability are probably just switching to use `Ninja` as a generator.